# ORM alternatives to ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, orm

To begin with this post in no ways undermines ActiveRecord. I am pretty happy with it, but for the sake of knowledge and to try a few options are there any other alternatives to ActiveRecord available? Has anybody used some other ORM than ActiveRecord, if yes then which ORM is that? Please share your experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try http://mongomapper.com/

Comment: If he was trying to access a Mongo Database that would be perfect. ActiveRecord is good to access SQL Databases so MongoMapper is a very poor suggestion or alternative.

Answer (score 4):

A place to look for ruby alternatives is https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/orm , the listed alternatives are:

- ORM Adapter
- Sequel
- DataMapper
- Squeel
- Ruby Object Mapper
- Og

Another one to mention is [Ohm](https://github.com/soveran/ohm), but only for Redis.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using [DataMapper](http://blog.codegram.com/2011/11/datamapper-an-alternative-to-activerecord)